# JavaScript working fine but showing error in console

Tags: javascript, jquery

Script is working fine but showing

> Type Error: $(...) is not a function in firebug console.

My script is as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    var $container = $('.answer');
    var $trigger   = $('.ques');

    $container.hide();
    $trigger.first().addClass('active').next().show();

    var fullWidth = $container.outerWidth(true);

    $trigger.on('click', function(e) {
        if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) {
            $trigger.removeClass('active').next().slideUp(300);
            $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown(300);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
})();
 </script>
```

Comment: You don't need the last set of parenthesis: `})();`

Comment: @MelanciaUK I think the last one `()` only!

Comment: @jogesh_pi It's a pair: `()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$()` call returns a jQuery object which contains reference to the `doucment` object, so that is not a function. Thus calling `()` at the end of `$()()` gives you the error.

Your code is working because the error is thrown after the dom ready handler is registered, so even if the call has thrown an error the dom ready handler is fired when it is ready.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ra0udvvy/)